# Simple mechanism to convert linear motion into 180 degrees rotation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, linear-motion

I want a simple mechanism to rotate something 180 degrees when another thing moves linearly past/through it. The below is what I have, but it can only work with an offset, so the movement is never fully 180 degrees. No gears/belts etc., it must be a simple mechanism. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Rack and pinion - easily controllable but you don’t want a gear…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two slots in 90 degrees angle on each other for the wheel[image]

Comment: Actually this does give 180 deg motion by doubling the idea i put above - suppose its basically a v simple rack and pinion like @solar Mike said. Bit more detailed diagram would help this be more useful i think.

Answer (score 2):

Without any furter information, the [Scotch Yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_yoke) is probably what you are after

[image: strong text]

Comment: That conversts rotary into linear - the opposite of what the OP requires. As show in your image a push from the right will be stuck on top-dead-centre.

Comment: @Transistor It can be used for both cases. Given the constraints that the OP provided I think it a simple and adequate solution. And although you are right there is a dead point, its and unstable equilibrium so even a small force it will move either way.

Comment: Its definitely an improvement on what I put - but yea it still suffers the same issue of there being a dead point, so one can't reliably get the full 180 degrees (though maybe 179.999...)

Comment: The other option is the [slider crank linkage mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider-crank_linkage) ( it still suffers from the same problem and its got more moving components).

Comment: @OliverWalters If you are worried about the dead point, you can use a slight offset between the rotation axis and the sliding axis. You will be sacrificing some degrees (but if radius is adequately large that can easily be under 1 deg.

Comment: Yea I want it to be 180 degrees exactly. I also have to worry about the friction/wear over 1000s of cycles and tolerances of the manufactured components, so I think in reality it has to be significantly less than 180 degrees to avoid these issues. It seems there is no way to get the full 180 degrees without gears/belts etc., hence I've marked this as the answer, many thanks